# Call sql query for each value of array in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I just started learning PHP and wanted to call SQL update query for all the values in the array. But I dont know to execute it in PHP.

```
 <?php
  $array = array("12345","23456","34567");
//now here how to call each value of arrayy
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $sql_points1    = "UPDATE user_earning SET points = points + '80' WHERE user_number = '//how to get value of number from array.'";
    $result_points1 = $conn->query($sql_points1);

    if ($result_points1 === TRUE) {
        echo "Current points added   ";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: We would need to see your array structure to determine how to get the values from it. If the data is sensitive, make some up.

Comment: Okay i will update my question.

Comment: Are you just asking how to get a value from an array?  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: no am asking how to get value from array and put in mysql query to update the value.

Comment: `$array = '12345'` isn't an array, but this is `$array = array(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: you also used mysql and sql-server. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `array("12345", "23456", "34567");` its like this to be exact

Comment: this edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16736688 should be rejected.

Comment: *"its like this to be exact"* - you should edit your question to hold the exact data. You're making your question unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- We were wrong about arrays all these years.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know Tim and I was about to post this under your (now deleted) answer: *"not to mention [the real array...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145499/call-sql-query-for-each-value-of-array-in-php#comment77259981_45145499)"*. But couldn't because you deleted it ;-)

Comment: the question is too unclear for my taste, where you want to update with the given arrays in one go like that. Sorry but I will pass on this one, good luck.

Comment: you probably want to loop through the array and generate a inlist which in turn you should use in your `update` statement (a generic solution .. should be working in php as well I believe)

Comment: You should take a look at the [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In your Foreach loop, the value of the current array element is assigned to $arr, so u can use that in your query.

```
$sql_points1 = "UPDATE user_earning SET points = points + '80' WHERE user_number = '$arr'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
<?php
  $array = array("12345","23456","34567");
//now here how to call each value of arrayy
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $sql_points1    = "UPDATE user_earning SET points = points + '80' WHERE user_number = $arr";
    $result_points1 = $conn->query($sql_points1);

    if ($result_points1 === TRUE) {
        echo "Current points added   ";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
?>
```